# Primefaces How commandButton in Dialog Refresh datatable in parent page

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, dialog, partial-page-refresh

I need your help in refreshing the values in the `datatable` component after clicking on the `commandButton` in the dialog. The jsf code is:

```
<h:form id="Requests">
  <h:panelGroup id="table">
    <p:fieldset id="Pendings">
      <p:dataTable id="PendingRequests">
      </p:dataTable>
      <p:dialog header="cert1">
        <p:commandButton value="Print" id="Print" actionListener="#{msd.updatePrint}" />
      </p:dialog>
    </p:fieldset>
  </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

The Print commandButton will fire a SQL UPDATE statement that will increment the count of the printing status in the database by 1. So if the value of the Printing Status column in the `dataTable` = 1, then this will increment by 1 and total will 2. Now, I want the `dataTable` in the parent page to pick up the change and to show that the Printing Status = 2.

I tried to add the below lines in the `updatePrint()` method but the increment is not shown in the dataTable:

```
public void updatePrint() {
//SQL UPDATE STATEMENT
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();

    context.update(":Requests:Pendings:PendingRequests");
}
```

I tried also to use ajax but I wasn't success :

```
<p:dialog header="cert1">
  <p:ajax event="close" update=":Requests:Pendings:PendingRequests" />
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: you realy don't have any errors? Is your project running in JSF development mode?

Comment: No I didn't get any error.

Comment: Is there a way to refresh the datatable component on close of the dialog to refresh the dataTable or to call a javascript function to reload the parent page or the dataTable

Comment: Fix your ajax error handling (or learn to read server logs and response body).